# Complex conditionals for classNames in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am currently re-writing one of my Web applications (made using jQuery and JavaScript) to use React.js instead.

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to render classNames when working with a complex conditional statement.

I have two states called `userChoseToMeetAlien` and `cupAndSaucerHaveArrived` in my main component class called AppContainer.

The initial state of the `userChoseToMeetAlien` and `cupAndSaucerHaveArrived` booleans are set to false as follows.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        userChoseToMeetAlien: false,
        cupAndSaucerHaveArrived: false
    };
}
```

I have a stateless component called `CupAndSaucer` and these states (mentioned above) are passed in as properties.

I would like to add different classes to the HTML (rendered in `CupAndSaucer`) depending on the values of these properties.

Here is the pseudocode of how I would like things to work:

```
 if(props.userChoseToMeetAlien is true AND props.cupAndSaucerHaveArrived is false) then
     add the move_animation class   
 else if(props.userChoseToMeetAlien is false AND props.cupAndSaucerHaveArrived is true)
     add the full_position class
 else 
     //both properties are false
     should have no classes
 end
```

Here is my `CupAndSaucer` component where I have attempted to add the classes.
As you can see it is not ideal as the `full_position` class is added when both `props.userChoseToMeetAlien` and `props.cupAndSaucerHaveArrived` are false.

```
const CupAndSaucer = function(props) {  
    return (<div id="cup_and_saucer_container" 
               className={((props.userChoseToMeetAlien === true  && props.cupAndSaucerHaveArrived === false) ? 'move_animation' : 'full_position')}>    
        </div>
    );

}
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this awesome library https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames
Something like this:

```
import cn from 'classnames';

const CupAndSaucer = function(props) { 

    const className = cn('some-default-class', {
      'move_animation': (props.userChoseToMeetAlien === true  && props.cupAndSaucerHaveArrived === false),
      'full_position': (props.userChoseToMeetAlien === false  && props.cupAndSaucerHaveArrived === false)
    });
    return (<div id="cup_and_saucer_container" 
               className={className}>    
        </div>
    );

}
```